# Is Erlang bad language for this app?

Tags: erlang

I am building **framework for realtime web applications**. I started to do it in **Elixir**, because 
it is modern way how to develop application for **Erlang VM**. **Erlang should be good if you need concurrency, fault tolerant, scalable apps (something like web server etc.).** That is exactly what i need.

**Question:** Realtime framework always need for instance keep information about who is interested in what. This will be accomplished by using publish/subscribe pattern. So i will have 1000 clients subscribing to topic "newest-message". I need to save those clients (pid of process representing each client) somewhere to later access them if content for topic "newest-message" appears. 
This is where i am confused if Erlang is really good for my framework.

**ETS** is probably the only option where to store shared data, but **ETS is always copying everything if you save/access records.** So that means copy 1000 pids always when i need to access them (instead of just iterating over some list, if i will do it for instance in c/java/python).
This will be probably great bottleneck if still copying many and many records from **ETS** (many clients, many subscriptions etc), i am right?

Comment: You frame this as a question about Erlang, but set arbitrary conditions for the architecture which are very un-Erlangish before you have even explored the problem space. I recommend you head over to #erlang or the ML to ask for advice before you jump to any more conclusions.

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/uwiger/gproc

Comment: RabbitMQ is written in Erlang and it does exactly, what you need. Check out, how they solved the problem or just use it.

Comment: Whether you use elixir or erlang is in one sense irrelevant as they both provide the same base properties, the properties of erlang, as elixir compiles down to erlang. So if one is suitable for this app then so will be the other one as well.

Comment: Do you **really** need to share all those pids? Keeping them in ETS will cost you very little even if it does entail copying, a pid is very small.

Comment: A final comment: are you looking for a reason to use erlang or looking for a reason not to use erlang? Two different things.

Comment: You can't use 'shared state' and 'scalability' in one sentence.

Comment: @rvirding: i want to use elixir, like that language. You are right, maybe i don't need to share those pids if i rework architecture. Hope that if i will save them in GenServer state, they will be not copied between each handle_call.

Comment: Passing arguments in a call does not mean copying them so if you pass them around there is no copying. Generally architectures for non-sharing systems and sharing system will look different. They have different properties and the sharing/non-sharing is a fundamental property.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing the state may be a sign of bad design. You can for example have process for each queue/topic and it will store its own list of subscribers. You send a message to that topic process and it in turn sends the message to clients. This way, you don't copy entire subscriber list.

If you need to process them in parallel, you can split the subscriber list between more processes.

The fault tolerance of Erlang is achieved, because it doesn't let you share state and you have to put more thought to the design, that will not involve state sharing, but will be efficient. This will pay off in the long run, so Erlang/Elixir is definitely good language for this kind of apps. Just look at RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

In my opnion, if you plan to save states like "who is interested in what" Erlang alone may not be a good idea. Of course, sometimes it is very convenient to pass everything in signals (like you'd do in Erlang), but when there is much content to store - lack of state in Erlang starts to hinder you rather than help.

On the other hand, you can keep a broad piece of convenience of Erlang and use it with a Java application, for example. Erlangs interface for Java enables you to connect both technologies quite easily, and at the same time you can use a Java app to store information for you (and save them somewhere, when necessary) and Erlang for the whole concurrent signaling real time part. Even better than that: you can still implement OTP with architecture like that, so you can create quite a lightweight application (because real-time logic is done by Erlang for you) being able to access stored data easily (because Java helps you here).

Comment: I would argue for the use of a data storage system that can interface with Erlang instead of simply offering another language in which another data storage system must be either contacted or implemented -- the jump to Java unnecessarily complicates things when the Erlang program could call any ODBC database, Postgres or Mnesia directly instead.

Comment: I see you are right. I intended it to be an example, because that's kind of a system I participated in building once, but I understand this could be misleading for a beginner.